# How can I check if the order email is being sent to a specific email

Tags: magento-1.9

How can I check if the order email in magento 1.9 is being sent to a specific email and if it contains a specific text. If yes, I would like to add text to the email template. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Login Admin panel,

Go to system > Transactional Emails > Add new Template > Select New Order Template > Load Template.

After loading, you can get the template content. Also, you would be able to modify them and save.

Where to set : System > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails > Order > New Order Confirmation Template > Here you can set you new template.

Also, insert your test email ID for testing in the field "Send Order Email Copy To".

Make an order and check the emails are getting sent or not.